# Check if private ssh-key has been added to ssh-agent

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

In `~/.ssh` I have `github` and `bitbucket` private key files. Both are encrypted, so when I `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github` I have to enter a password.

I have a bash script to automate `git` commands. If the `github` and/or `bitbucket` identities have NOT been added yet, then I want to `ssh-add` them.

I'm looking for a function like:

```sh
has_identity_been_added ~/.ssh/github
```

To simply check if the private, encrypted key file has been added.

I found:

- `ssh-add -l` prints out a string of text for each identity... and I don't know what it is, but it's not the key file name
- `ssh-add -L` prints the public key, which I'm not storing on my local machine, so I'm not sure how to verify against it, without asking for the private key file's password again.

Both of those print the name I gave to the key file like `reed@laptop-x1834` (I think that was the automatic name, cause I didn't specify `-C` in the `ssh-keygen`, if memory serves).

I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't want to rely upon the `ssh-keygen -C "whatever_name"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh-add -l` print out fingerprint of the keys added.

You can get the fingerprint of a public key with :

```
ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Anyway to get the fingerprint from the private key file, without needing to enter the password? I don't keep the `.pub` around.

Comment: `ssh-keygen` should work on private key as well.